# Obter palavras mais usadas de uma string

Tags: php, string

Tenho uma grande string:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor non felis quis dignissim. Morbi varius arcu lorem, eget efficitur nibh interdum vitae. Aenean tristique hendrerit diam a consequat. Nunc eleifend dolor ut rhoncus sollicitudin. Suspendisse tincidunt sodales turpis et egestas. Sed maximus libero malesuada lacus tempor, quis placerat nunc varius. Nam eget lectus imperdiet, lobortis mi sit amet, tristique justo. Fusce in felis et erat auctor vehicula quis dapibus libero. In commodo a leo eu eleifend.
```

como posso capturar as 4 palavras mais repetidas nesta *string*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tens de usar 3 passos:

- [str_word_count()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)

Este método conta o numero de palavras numa *string*. Quando se passa `1` como parâmetro, retorna uma array com todas as palavras.

- [array_count_values()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Este método retorna uma nova array, onde os *valores* da inicial são *chaves* e os *valores* dessas *chaves* são a freqüência desse valor.

- [arsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)

Este método organiza a array para ter os valores mais altos no inicio.

#### Exemplo:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor non felis quis dignissim. Morbi varius arcu lorem, eget efficitur nibh interdum vitae. Aenean tristique hendrerit diam a consequat. Nunc eleifend dolor ut rhoncus sollicitudin. Suspendisse tincidunt sodales turpis et egestas. Sed maximus libero malesuada lacus tempor, quis placerat nunc varius. Nam eget lectus imperdiet, lobortis mi sit amet, tristique justo. Fusce in felis et erat auctor vehicula quis dapibus libero. In commodo a leo eu eleifend.';
$palavras = array_count_values(str_word_count($string, 1));
arsort($palavras);
var_dump($palavras);
```

#### Vai dar:

```
array(64) {
  ["quis"]=>
  int(3)
  ["tristique"]=>
  int(2)
  ["varius"]=>
  int(2)
  ["a"]=>
  int(2)
  ["eleifend"]=>
  int(2)
  ["et"]=>
  int(2)
  ["libero"]=>
  int(2)
  ["felis"]=>
  int(2)
  ["eget"]=>
  int(2)
  etc...
```

Comment: @user3163662 tem maneiras diferentes. Como vai querer usar o resultado? uma a uma, dentro de uma array? importa o numero de vezes que apareceu ou somente que é uma das _x_ primeiras?

Comment: És muito rápido a responder... ou eu estou a ficar velho... Acabei por usar o mesmo que tu, mas fiz uma função toda bonita para lidar com o assunto :P

Comment: @Zuul: Aqui na Suécia está frio, temos de mexer os dedos rápido para aquecer :)

Answer (score 3):

Essencialmente, será necessário partir o texto em palavras para uma matriz. Depois precisamos contar os repetidos, ordenar o resultado do maior número de repetidos para o menor número de repetidos e finalmente ficar apenas com os primeiros X.

Para o efeito vamos usar a função de PHP [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) para contar os valores na matriz, a função de PHP [`str_word_count()`](http://php.net/str_word_count) para contar o número de vezes que a palavra existe no texto fornecido, a função de PHP [`arsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) para ordenar a matriz por ordem descendente sem perder a relação com a chave e por fim a função de PHP [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) para ficar na matriz apenas a quantidade pretendida de palavras:

```
/**
 * Palavras Mais Repetidas
 * Com base no texto recebido, devolver as primeiras X
 * palavras mais repetidas
 *
 * @param string $texto O texto a avaliar
 * @param integer $quantidade A quantidade de palavras a devolver
 *
 * @return array Matriz com as palavras mais repetidas
 */
function palavrasMaisRepetidas($texto="", $quantidade=4) {

  $palavras = array_count_values(str_word_count($texto, 1));

  arsort($palavras);

  return array_slice($palavras, 0, $quantidade);
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```
$texto = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor non felis quis dignissim. Morbi varius arcu lorem, eget efficitur nibh interdum vitae. Aenean tristique hendrerit diam a consequat. Nunc eleifend dolor ut rhoncus sollicitudin. Suspendisse tincidunt sodales turpis et egestas. Sed maximus libero malesuada lacus tempor, quis placerat nunc varius. Nam eget lectus imperdiet, lobortis mi sit amet, tristique justo. Fusce in felis et erat auctor vehicula quis dapibus libero. In commodo a leo eu eleifend.";

var_dump(palavrasMaisRepetidas($texto, 5));
```

**Resultado:**

```
array(4) {
  ["quis"]=>
  int(3)
  ["tristique"]=>
  int(2)
  ["varius"]=>
  int(2)
  ["a"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

---

Ver exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Ni4RQK).

Answer (score 2):

As respostas do Sergio e do Zuul provavelmente têm performance melhor, mas segue uma solução didática que usa [`strtok`](http://php.net/strtok) para quebrar o texto em palavras, e faz a contagem manualmente. Esta solução é *case-insensitive*.

```
<?php
$texto = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor non felis quis dignissim. Morbi varius arcu lorem, eget efficitur nibh interdum vitae. Aenean tristique hendrerit diam a consequat. Nunc eleifend dolor ut rhoncus sollicitudin. Suspendisse tincidunt sodales turpis et egestas. Sed maximus libero malesuada lacus tempor, quis placerat nunc varius. Nam eget lectus imperdiet, lobortis mi sit amet, tristique justo. Fusce in felis et erat auctor vehicula quis dapibus libero. In commodo a leo eu eleifend.";
$frequencias = array();
$separadores = " .,;:!?/\"'()[]{}\n\r\t";
$palavra = strtok($texto, $separadores);
while($palavra !== false) {
    if(array_key_exists(strtoupper($palavra), $frequencias)) {
        $frequencias[strtoupper($palavra)]++;
    } else {
        $frequencias[strtoupper($palavra)] = 1;
    }
    $palavra = strtok($separadores);
}
arsort($frequencias);
print_r($frequencias);
```

<sup>http://ideone.com/xlpD4b</sup>

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [QUIS] => 3
    [ET] => 2
    [VARIUS] => 2
    [IN] => 2
    [TRISTIQUE] => 2
    [A] => 2
    [LIBERO] => 2
    [LOREM] => 2
    [ELEIFEND] => 2
    [NUNC] => 2
    [FELIS] => 2
    [EGET] => 2
    [DOLOR] => 2
    [SIT] => 2
    [AMET] => 2
    [LEO] => 1
    [TEMPOR] => 1
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara, tenta algo assim:

Explode essa string pelo espaço usando o explode:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php

Depois usa o array_count_value:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-count-values.php

Ae basta pegar os 4 primeiros espaços do array!

OBS: Pra ficar mais facil tenta retirar do array palavras de uso frequente como e,a,do,de,da,para,então,assim e etc :D